# Using the Apache Mahout machine learning libraries

Tags: apache, machine-learning, hadoop, mahout

I've been working with the Apache Mahout machine learning libaries in my free time a bit over the past few weeks. I'm curious to hear about how others are using these libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article is fairly thorough and has good examples:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout/index.html

Comment: I'll give you credit for the answer... I was initially hoping to see 'real-world' examples, but this article is well written and a great resource for all mahout users. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I used Mahout to implement a distributed recommender system. 
Our project was to develop a mobile platform to create collaborative filtering recommendations.
We gathered data from the users and then used Mahout + Hadoop to make the recommendations.

The projects is described here

http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-676/paper9.pdf

http://egc2012.labri.fr/abstracts/139.pdf

And some of it in my blog here:
http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com.br/